# ganeti-metad bind address based on cluster configuration

Tags: linux, virtualization, ganeti

On my machine (debian jessie) `ganeti-metad` listens on all interfaces:

```
# netstat -lepn | grep metad
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          66528       32831/ganeti-metad
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     383      1/init              /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     66525    32831/ganeti-metad  /var/run/ganeti/socket/ganeti-metad
```

Currently I'm using the firewall to limit access, but I preferr to change the interface thThere is a argument in `ganeti-metad` to provide address, but it also says that default is based on cluster configuration:

```
# /usr/sbin/ganeti-metad --help
ganeti-metad (ganeti) version v2.12.4
Usage: ganeti-metad [OPTION...]
  -b ADDR  --bind=ADDR        Bind address (default depends on cluster configuration)
```

Which ganeti cluster configuration parameter drives the interface that `ganeti-metad` listens on? How to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if this is what you're trying to achieve ...

Did you tried to specify it inside `/etc/default/ganeti`, for example

```
# Default arguments for Ganeti daemons
NODED_ARGS=""
MASTERD_ARGS=""
RAPI_ARGS=""
CONFD_ARGS=""
LUXID_ARGS=""
METAD_ARGS="-b XX.XX.XX.XX"
```

XX.XX.XX.XX being the IP ganeti-metad should bind to?

Comment: Yeah, its a kind of solution, but then I need to do it on every node manualy and watch not to run `gnt-cluster redist-conf` because it will overwrite IP making it not working..

Comment: Got your points: Regarding the distribution problem: Yeah, have no solution for this at hand, but maybe you could use a configuration management tool for this. Regarding `gnt-cluster redist-conf`: At least on my clusters, running `gnt-cluster (ganeti v2.11.6) 2.11.6` and `gnt-cluster (ganeti 2.15.1-1~bpo8+1) 2.15.1`, `/etc/default/ganeti` isn't distributed; maybe you could check this on your system(s). Another idea, not sure if this is possible for you: You could bind `ganeti-metad` to 127.0.0.1. Hope this helps, somehow.

Comment: @neutrinus: Did this help?

Comment: Yup, redist doesn't distribute `/etc/default/ganeti`, setting to `-b 127.0.0.1` worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Default arguments for Ganeti daemons are in `/etc/default/ganeti`.

So add a new line `METAD_ARGS="-p 81"` to move `ganeti-metad` to port 81, or `METAD_ARGS="-b abb.bbb.ccc.ddd -p 81"` to also move the daemon to other interface.

To get this setup activated:

1. run `gnt-cluster redist-conf` on ganeti master to propagate config in the cluster
2. kill the running `ganeti-metad` daemons an all nodes. They will be restarted when Ganeti needs it, don't worry, i.e. when `gnt-instance add ...` is executed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing default arguments for daemons. Great, but as far as I understand it would result in all `ganeti-metad` trying to listen on same IP on all nodes? Every node has different IP, so it would not work. Can I instead provide a interface?

Comment: Note for others: `redist-conf` doesn't populate the `/etc/default/ganeti` file.